# LAMP Stack cant read from mysql database correctly but can't insert correctly. Function "succeeds" with no errors but database doesn't update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, lamp

I'm a Sophomore, and the new Webmaster for this community service organization at my University. I'm updating a 10-15 year old website hosted on InMotion, and am currently in the process of moving it to a LAMP stack I configured and set up myself on AWS, and remaking the website's structure one by one. So far I've got it all working, except I can't add onto the database correctly. The reading from database and displaying tables pages all work though, so I'm not sure what's wrong with the inserting functions. I've tried everything, but everything looks right to me...

When adding an announcement, as long as all the checks go through it goes to the "announcement added successfully page"

As a note, the PHP version of the site that was hosted on InMotion was version 5, and I updated it to 7.2 when I made the AWS LAMP stack. To fix the mysql and regex deprecations, I imported a couple wrappers I found on github that fixed it (allowing me to read from the database correctly).

Here are the relevant code blocks. I think I have them correctly sequenced and they look right to me.

```
<!-- IN add_announcement.php -->
            <h2>Add an Announcement</h2>
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['addannouncement'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['addannouncement']);
                echo ("\t\t\t<p>Announcement added successfully!</p>\n");
            } else {
            ?>
            <form action="process.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Add Announcement</legend>
                    <?php
                    if ($form->num_errors > 0) {
                        echo ("\t\t\t\t\t<p style=\"font-weight:bold;color:#f00;\">".$form->num_errors." error(s) found</p>\n");
                    }
                    ?>

                    /* ol and li stuff for forms*/
                    ...

                    <input type="hidden" id="subaddannouncement" name="subaddannouncement" value="1" />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
<!-- IN process.php, WITHIN AN IF LOOP-->
    /* User submitted add announcement form */
    else if (isset($_POST['subaddannouncement'])) {
        $this->procAddAnnouncement();
    }
<!-- IN process.php -->
    /*
     * procAddAnnouncement - Validates and processes requests to add an announcement to the database
     */
    function procAddAnnouncement()
    {
        global $session, $form;

        /* Announcement add attempt */
        $retval = $session->addAnnouncement($_POST['txt_Title'], $_POST['txtarea_Body']);

        file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("ERROR DEBUG: retval is " . $retval, TRUE));

        /* Announcement Add Successful */
        if ($retval == 0) {
            $_SESSION['addannouncement'] = true;
            header("Location: " . $session->referrer);
        }
        /* Error found with form */
        else if ($retval == 1) {
            $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
            $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
            header("Location: " . $session->referrer);
        }
        /* Announcement add attempt failed */
        else if ($retval == 2) {
            $_SESSION['addannouncement'] = false;
            header("Location: " . $session->referrer);
        }
    }

<!-- IN session.php function addAnnouncement($subtitle, $subbody)-->
    function addAnnouncement($subtitle, $subbody)
    {
        global $database, $form;

        /* Announcement Title Error Checking */
        ...

        /* Announcement Body Error Checking */
        ...

        /* Set Announcement Post Date */
        ...

        /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
        if ($form->num_errors > 0) {
            return 1; // Errors with form
        }
        /* No errors, add the new announcement to the database */
        else {
            if ($database->addNewAnnouncement($subtitle,$subbody,$subtime)) {
                return 0; //Event signup added succesfully
            } else {
                return 2; //Event signup attempt failed
            }
        }
    }
<!-- IN database.php -->
    /**
     * addNewAnnouncement - Inserts announcement title, body, and post date into the database
     */
    function addNewAnnouncement($title, $body, $date)
    {
        $q = "INSERT INTO `" . TBL_ANNOUNCEMENTS . "` VALUES ('','$title','$date','$body')";
        $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
        return $result;
    }
```

[IMAGE OF Directory Structure for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIzBo.png)

Comment: Triple check your username, password and dbame.

Comment: Try to manually run `commit` in mysql. The records are sometimes not reflected back

Comment: You are still using `mysql_query`

Answer (score 1):

In your database.php you are still using mysql_query.

mysql_query was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7.0.0 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Since you are using 7.2, it won't work.

Use [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead.

Note: With mysqli_query, the parameter order has changed.

```
mysqli_query($connection, $query)

vs

mysql_query($query, $connection)
```